# How to display a URL content in unity debuglog

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made this function to show URL content in DebugLOG. Is there any mistake here? Or maybe i have a bad aproach?

```
 IEnumerator Web()
    {
        using (WWW www = new WWW(servicesURL))
        {
            yield return www;
            Debug.Log(www.text);

        }

    }
```

For any website it returns this:

```
<noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript>
```

Comment: What URL are you loading?

Comment: I've tried pleantyof them from the simplest one - like only with one text to same more developed examples. Do have any examples of sites which will be able to load?

Comment: I took your code and told it to load "www.google.com" and I got back `<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="description">` (and then tons more).

Comment: I've got for the Google.com the same error as previous. Do You have any idea What could be the couse?

Comment: No idea at all. What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2017.3

Comment: I've got 2017.2, so its possible they introduced a bug. I'm using your exact code.

Comment: I can confirm it's working on 2017.2 and not working on 2017.3 (at least on my machine)

Comment: @Draco18s i have opened this script in empty project and it worked so the problem is in my project settings i guess. But still i have no idea what could be the reason.

Comment: i fixed it by removing the object and repleacing it with the new one, and attaching exactly the same scrict. i don't know why but it worked.

Comment: Weird! No idea what setting could have caused that either.

Comment: Probably the servicesURL being accessed stops bot requests. Are you sure `https://www.google.com` really worked for you?